# How to create a drill-down report called from Java?

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports, drilldown

I have created Balances report using Jaspersoft Studio. I have also created hyperlink on a field in this report with below properties:

```
Link Type: ReportExecution
Parameters: _report
```

The value of above parameter is "GLLedger" which is another jasper report present in the same folder.

In Java, when I invoke this report, and click the hyperlink, then GLLedger report does not appear but get below warning on console:

> Hyperlink of type ReportExecution
>   Implement your own JRHyperlinkListener to manage this type of event.

In Java, I am using JasperViewer to preview report. Below is the code:

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, hm, connection);
JasperViewer v = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
v.setVisible(true);
```

Can you please guide as how to call another report from one jasper report?

Comment: you want to test hyperlink in Jasper Studio ?

Comment: When I click on it in Jasper Studio, then nothing happens, no errors. Also ledger report does not open.

Comment: ReportExecution is feature of Jasper Server not jasper studio.

Comment: @FahadAnjum not for Jasper Studio, but you can use it in Swing, which is what OP seems to be doing `new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you like to use this in a swing application your main problem (at least in jasper report version <6.1.1) is that you have no direct method to add a `JRHyperLinkListener`

From source code of `JRViewer`:

> //FIXME add a method to do addHyperlinkListener without subclassing
>        `protected JRViewerPanel createViewerPanel(){return new JRViewerPanel(viewerContext);}`

I will show you a way how you can subclass this class, implement the `JRHyperlinkListener` and open a new frame with a report name received from link.

## Java code

Creating a class that extends the `net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewer` and implements the `net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRHyperlinkListener`, I'm adding imports since library have old classes with same name,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPrintHyperlink;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewer;
import net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewerPanel;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRHyperlinkListener;

public class HyperLinkTest extends JRViewer implements JRHyperlinkListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6429615130889276357L;

    public HyperLinkTest(JasperPrint jrPrint){
        super(jrPrint);
    }

    /**
     * Since JRViewerPanel is protected our only way to add listener is
     * to Override
     */
    @Override
    protected JRViewerPanel createViewerPanel()
    {
        JRViewerPanel panel =  new JRViewerPanel(viewerContext);
        panel.addHyperlinkListener(this);
        return panel;
    }

    /**
     * The listener gets the hyperlink reference and open relative report
     */
    @Override
    public void gotoHyperlink(JRPrintHyperlink arg) throws JRException {
        JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("jasper/" + arg.getHyperlinkReference() + ".jrxml");
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap<String, Object>());
        HyperLinkTest nextReport = new HyperLinkTest(jasperPrint);
        openReport("Navigated to", JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE, nextReport);        
    }

    /**
     * static method that creates a frame and adds the JRViewer to it and 
     * open a new frame with the viewer
     */
    public static void openReport(String title, int defaultCloseOperation, JRViewer hyperLinkReport){
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(defaultCloseOperation);
            frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.getContentPane().add(hyperLinkReport,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
      });
    }

    /**
     *  Main method to test
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException {
        JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("jasper/hyperlink1.jrxml");
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap<String, Object>());
        HyperLinkTest test = new HyperLinkTest(jasperPrint);
        openReport("Test hyperlink", JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE, test);

    }   

}
```

## Jrxml (reports)

As can be seen in code I'm using `hyperlinkType="ReportExecution"` and in passing name of next report in `hyperlinkReferenceExpression`.

**Report 1 (hyperlink1.jrxml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="hyperlink1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="601103bc-66ab-45a5-8422-ccb6f3e02ec2">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="50">
            <textField hyperlinkType="ReportExecution">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="8dc8f664-60b3-4b10-8a55-23120bea1f85"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Hello"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA["hyperlink2"]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

**Report 2 (hyperlink2.jrxml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="hyperlink1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="601103bc-66ab-45a5-8422-ccb6f3e02ec2">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="50">
            <textField hyperlinkType="ReportExecution">
                <reportElement x="113" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="8dc8f664-60b3-4b10-8a55-23120bea1f85"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["World"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <anchorNameExpression><![CDATA["World"]]></anchorNameExpression>
                <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA["hyperlink1"]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

## Result

First window will open with *"Hello"*, if you click *"Hello"*, second window will open with *"World"*

[image: Output]

> **Notes:** If I did this application probably I would pre-compile all `.jrxml` to `.jasper`, hence avoid compiling during run-time and probably I would have used multiple classes (1 for frame, 1 for viewer) avoiding static methods, however I have simplified to better fit SO format, concentrating on showing how a `JRHyperLinkListener` can be implemented in a Swing application.

## How to pass report parameters and other data

> Can you please tell me how to pass connection Object and other parameters from first report to second from this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44486778/how-to-create-a-drill-down-report-in-called-from-java/44488959?noredirect=1#comment76062678_44488959)

To pass objects (fields, parameters, variables or any other expression) to the `JRHyperlinkListener` you should `hyperlinkParameter` in jrxml.

**Example (see the `hyperlinkParameter` and it's `hyperlinkParameterExpression`)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="hyperlink1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="601103bc-66ab-45a5-8422-ccb6f3e02ec2">
    <parameter name="reportDate" class="java.util.Date" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    ....
            <textField hyperlinkType="ReportExecution">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="8dc8f664-60b3-4b10-8a55-23120bea1f85"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Hello"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA["hyperlink2"]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
                <hyperlinkParameter name="reportTime">
                    <hyperlinkParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{reportDate}]]></hyperlinkParameterExpression>
                </hyperlinkParameter>
            </textField>
        ....
</jasperReport>
```

This parameter can now be accessed by the `JRHyperlinkListener`, in example I pass it to parameter map for next report, naturally the `jphlp.getValue()` will continue to be `instanceof java.util.Date`

```
@Override
public void gotoHyperlink(JRPrintHyperlink arg) throws JRException {
    Map<String, Object> nextReportParams = new HashMap<>();
    List<JRPrintHyperlinkParameter> params = arg.getHyperlinkParameters().getParameters();
    for (JRPrintHyperlinkParameter jphlp : params) {
        if ("reportTime".equals(jphlp.getName())){
            nextReportParams.put("previousReportTime",jphlp.getValue());                
        }
    }

    JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("jasper/" + arg.getHyperlinkReference() + ".jrxml");
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, nextReportParams);
    HyperLinkTest nextReport = new HyperLinkTest(jasperPrint);
    openReport("Navigated to", JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE, nextReport);        
}
```

> **Notes:** Watch out passing main report datasource (this will be at the
>   end, you cannot re-use it, if you do not rewind it first) and
>   connection (this may be closed), it's better to pass a new connection to next report.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Can you please tell me how to pass connection Object and other parameters from first report to second.

Comment: @Moazzam ok I added it in post, see updated post, last section